# How can i apply native join query in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

Here are my entity classes.

**JobPost.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_post")
public class JobPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "job_post_id")
    private Long jobPostId;

    @Column(name = "job_title")
    private String jobTitle;

    @Column(name = "job_description")
    private String jobDescription;

    @Column(name = "vacancy")
    private int vacancy;

    @Column(name = "posted_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date postedDate;

    @Column(name = "total_applicants")
    private int totalApplicants;
    
}
```

**JobApplication.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_application")
public class JobApplication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "job_application_id")
    private Long jobApplicationId;

    @Column(name = "job_post_id")
    private Long jobPostId;

    @Column(name = "applicant_id")
    private Long applicantId;
}
```

**Applicant.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicant")
public class Applicant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "applicant_id")
    private Long applicantId;

    @Column(name = "applicant_name")
    private String applicantName;

    @Column(name = "applicant_mobile_no")
    private String applicantMobileNo;

    @Column(name = "applicant_email")
    private String applicantEmail;

}
```

My main goal is to listing the **ApplicantList** on **JobPostId**. I am totally new in Spring data JPA. Is JPA mappings are correct?. I don't know which query I should fire in order to fetch the applicantList based on jobPostId.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use JpaMappings and use SpringData instead of using native query.
Steps to follow:
**Many-To-Many:**

Use JoinTable to directly map JobPost and Applicant instead of creating a separate class.

Link for help:
https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-mapping

Use SpringData JPA  findOne or findById method (depends on spring version). If you use EAGER fetch then it will give you all Applicants associated with the JobPost Id.

**One-To-Many**

Keep JobApplication class and use OneToMany annotation.

Link for help:
https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-one-to-many-mapping

Query:

```
@Query("select a from JobPost j inner join j.jobApplicantList ja inner join ja.applicant a where j.jobPostId=:jobPostId")
    List<String> findAllJobApplicants(@Param("jobPostId") Long jobPostId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should configure the mappings in such a way.To do this, you only need two entities
JobPost.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "job_post")
    public class JobPost {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "job_title")
        private String jobTitle;
    
        @Column(name = "job_description")
        private String jobDescription;
    
        @Column(name = "vacancy")
        private int vacancy;
    
        @Column(name = "posted_date")
        @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date postedDate;
    
        @Column(name = "total_applicants")
        private int totalApplicants;
    
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "applicant_job_post",
                joinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "job_post_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
                }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        })
        private Set<Applicant> applicants;
    
        public JobPost() {
        }
    
        public void addApplicant(Applicant applicant) {
            applicants.add(applicant);
            applicant.getJobPosts().add(this);
        }
    
        public void removeApplicant(Applicant applicant) {
            applicants.remove(applicant);
            applicant.getJobPosts().remove(this);
        }
   }
```

Applicant.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicant")
public class Applicant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "applicant_name")
    private String applicantName;

    @Column(name = "applicant_mobile_no")
    private String applicantMobileNo;

    @Column(name = "applicant_email")
    private String applicantEmail;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applicants")
    private Set<JobPost> jobPosts;

    public Applicant() {
    }

    public void addJobPost(JobPost jobPost) {
        jobPosts.add(jobPost);
        jobPost.getApplicants().add(this);
    }

    public void removeJobPost(JobPost jobPost) {
        jobPosts.remove(jobPost);
        jobPost.getApplicants().remove(this);
    }
}
```